# label columns using *

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to assign column names using SELECT * with a prefix. It is hard to explain so see this example.

```
$connect->prepare("
SELECT 
     user.firstName as prefix_firstName,
     user.lastName as prefix_lastName
   FROM user
WHERE user.ID = '5'
    ");
```

What I would like is to be able to use is `user.*` and assign a prefix as prefix_ using *. Like this:

```
SELECT 
   user.* as prefix_*
```

It would assign each column to prefix_ like prefix_firstName without having to call each column and assign it with an `as` prefix_columnName. Like:

```
SELECT
  user.firstName as prefix_firstName,
  user.lastName as prefix_lastName
```

I hope that is explained well enough.

Updated
Thanks.. The reason is, I have 3 people that I need to pull from the same table. using

```
SELECT user.*,
       admin.*,
       creator.*
FROM 
     user
LEFT JOIN
     user as admin
ON
     admin.ID = user.adminID
LEFT JOIN
     user as creator
ON
     creator.ID = user.creatorID
WHERE
     user.ID = '5'
```

As example all 3 selects(`user.*`,`admin.*`,`creator.*`) would all create the same firstName variable which would overwrite iteself. I thought maybe there was a shorter way than doing it like this.

```
SELECT
    user.firstName,
    user.lastName,
    admin.firstName as admin_firstName,
    admin.lastName as admin_lastName,
    creator.firstName as creator_firstName,
    creator.lastName as creator_lastName
FROM 
     user
LEFT JOIN
     user as admin
ON
     admin.ID = user.adminID
LEFT JOIN
     user as creator
ON
     creator.ID = user.creatorID
WHERE
     user.ID = '5'
```

That is just an snippet, there are actually 37 columns in the user table that needs to be pulled for each of the 3 users.

Thanks!

Comment: no, but you could write a function to build the query creating the aliasis.

Comment: Or you could assign the prefix with PHP as you get the data out of MySQL

Comment: the question is: *why?*

Comment: @Fred-ii- Karen knows: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6inwzOooXRU

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. I thought it was something like [this...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oALxLNOhI6I) @Dagon

Comment: @Fred-ii- well this has a lot more merit than: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33091715/run-exe-from-memory-with-php-and-winapi

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible using sql. If the query is assembled dynamically within php code, then the php code can build the query as string to include each field individually with an alias.

Comment: Yes, that is probably my only choice.